# Set session cookies in play framework testing using selenium hd

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do some unit testing using selenium hd. I currently have the following code:

```
    browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/")
    browser.$("#email").text("michele@sample.com")
    browser.$("#password").text("secret")
    browser.$("#loginbutton").click()
    browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/michele")
```

But I would like to be to be able to set a session cookie instead of having to do this for every test.

I tried to do something like this

```
    browser.webDriver.manage().addCookie( new Cookie("PLAY_SESSION",
      "1dd6811c9df64e03a892f55f57dd0f1190656d88-email%3Amichele%40sample.com") )
```

but doesnt work out, as I get a null pointer exception when I try to retrieve the cookie using
        `browser.getCookie("PLAY_SESSION").getValue()` must contain`("michele@sample.com")`

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is the type of `browser`?

Comment: @senia: It's TestBrowser which extends FluentAdapter

Comment: Did you figure it out? Struggling with the same here

Answer (score 0):

Since michele@sample.com is converted into michele%40sample.com hence  try using 
michele%40sample.com  instead of michele@sample.com

```
browser.getCookie("PLAY_SESSION").getValue() must contain("michele%40sample.com")
```